# Select Statement using Stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql

May I ask on how to call a method when the content of the stored procedure is about select statement? (Using postgreSQL)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE select_table(table_name VARCHAR(255))
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM' || ' ' || quote_ident(table_name));
END $$;

CALL select_table('employee_table');
```

EDITED(USING FUNCTION)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_table(table_name VARCHAR(255))
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM table_name
    RETURN table_name;
END $$;
```

Comment: If you want to return a result set, use a function, not a procedure.

Comment: Can you check if what's wrong on my function? Sorry this is my first time to use function

Comment: You don't have a return type for your function and your return statement is just some syntax you made up. Go get a fresh cup of tea/coffee and read the pl/pgsql section of the official manuals. There are example functions there.

Comment: **1.** You can get data out of a [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) through `out` or `inout` arguments or side-effects (inserting your output to some outside table you'll later find it in) but if you're not forced to use a procedure, a function will be much easier to work with. **2.** Define the return type for your [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) `create function select_table(table_name regclass) returns table(a int, b text) language plpgsql as $$ begin RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT a, b from '||table_name;`

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL procedures doesn't execute any select statements and doesn't have return.
For returning data you can use functions. But functions also cannot return different structural data, examples:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fr_test()
RETURNS TABLE(id integer, bookname character varying)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
begin
    return QUERY
    SELECT tb.id, tb.bookname from rbac.books tb;
end;
$function$
;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fr_test()
RETURNS setof public.books 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
begin
    return QUERY
    SELECT * from public.books;
end;
$function$
;
```

But for returning difference tables you can do it using procedures and using `out refcursor`, like as in Oracle. For example:

```
create or replace procedure pr_test(OUT r1 refcursor) 
as $$
begin
    open r1 for 
    select * from public.books;
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```